# How can I implement a TLS-SRP connection

Tags: java, ssl

I have a client/server remote desktop application , client will connect to server for remote control over server desktop. I would like to establish a TLS-SRP to protect the channel, since SRP support mutual authentication and forward secrecy. My question is that will TLS-SRP suitable for remote desktop application, I come across with TLS-DHE_RSA too which will be more secure?

After googling, it seems like TLS-SRP only support on web based application? JSSE doesn't support SRP too.